# Generate Swagger.json using Springfox for OASP4j (Spring boot) cxf Rest services

Tags: maven, spring-boot, cxf, swagger, springfox

I am trying to generate a swagger.json for our project that is based on OASP4J. It uses spring boot and the Apache cxf service framework to develop the Rest services.
I have already tried different tutorial but nothing seems to work.
The main problem is that the file is generated but the api list is empty.Every rest service is under this path [localhost:8081/attivazioni/services/rest/general/v1/](http://localhost:8081/attivazioni/services/rest/general/v1/)

SpringBootApp.java

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { EndpointAutoConfiguration.class })
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "\"it.lispa.sire.attivazioni" }, basePackageClasses = { AdvancedRevisionEntity.class })
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true)
public class SpringBootApp {

  /**
   * Entry point for spring-boot based app
   *
   * @param args - arguments
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    SpringApplication.run(SpringBootApp.class, args);
  }
}
```

JerseyConfig.java

```
@Component
@ApplicationScope("/attivazioni")
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

  public JerseyConfig() {

    BeanConfig swaggerConfig = new BeanConfig();
    swaggerConfig.setBasePath("/attivazioni");
    SwaggerConfigLocator.getInstance().putConfig(SwaggerContextService.CONFIG_ID_DEFAULT, swaggerConfig);

    packages(getClass().getPackage().getName(), ApiListingResource.class.getPackage().getName());
  }

}
```

CombinedSwaggerResourcesProvider.java

```
@Component
@Primary
public class CombinedSwaggerResourcesProvider implements SwaggerResourcesProvider {

  @Resource
  private InMemorySwaggerResourcesProvider inMemorySwaggerResourcesProvider;

  @Override
  public List<SwaggerResource> get() {

    SwaggerResource jerseySwaggerResource = new SwaggerResource();
    jerseySwaggerResource.setLocation("/attivazioni/swagger.json");
    jerseySwaggerResource.setSwaggerVersion("2.0");
    jerseySwaggerResource.setName("Jersey");

    return Stream.concat(Stream.of(jerseySwaggerResource), this.inMemorySwaggerResourcesProvider.get().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }

}
```

ServiceConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWs
@ImportResource({ "classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" })
public class ServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

  /** Logger instance. */
  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServiceConfig.class);

  /** The services "folder" of an URL. */
  public static final String URL_FOLDER_SERVICES = "services";

  public static final String URL_PATH_SERVICES = "/private/" + URL_FOLDER_SERVICES;

  public static final String URL_FOLDER_REST = "/rest";

  public static final String URL_FOLDER_WEB_SERVICES = "/ws";

  public static final String URL_PATH_REST_SERVICES = URL_PATH_SERVICES + "/" + URL_FOLDER_REST;

  public static final String URL_PATH_WEB_SERVICES = URL_PATH_SERVICES + "/" + URL_FOLDER_WEB_SERVICES;

  @Value("${security.expose.error.details}")
  boolean exposeInternalErrorDetails;

  @Inject
  private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  @Inject
  private ObjectMapperFactory objectMapperFactory;

  @Bean(name = "cxf")
  public SpringBus springBus() {

    return new SpringBus();
  }

  @Bean
  public JacksonJsonProvider jacksonJsonProvider() {

    return new JacksonJsonProvider(this.objectMapperFactory.createInstance());
  }

  @Bean
  public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {

    CXFServlet cxfServlet = new CXFServlet();
    ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistration = new ServletRegistrationBean(cxfServlet, URL_PATH_SERVICES + "/*");
    return servletRegistration;
  }

  @Bean
  public Server jaxRsServer() {

    // List<Object> restServiceBeans = new
    // ArrayList<>(this.applicationContext.getBeansOfType(RestService.class).values());
    Collection<Object> restServices = findRestServices();
    if (restServices.isEmpty()) {
      LOG.info("No REST Services have been found. Rest Endpoint will not be enabled in CXF.");
      return null;
    }
    Collection<Object> providers = this.applicationContext.getBeansWithAnnotation(Provider.class).values();

    JAXRSServerFactoryBean factory = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
    factory.setBus(springBus());
    factory.setAddress(URL_FOLDER_REST);
    factory.setServiceBeans(new ArrayList<>(restServices));
    factory.setProviders(new ArrayList<>(providers));
    return factory.create();
  }

  private Collection<Object> findRestServices() {

    return this.applicationContext.getBeansWithAnnotation(Path.class).values();
  }

  @Bean
  public RestServiceExceptionFacade restServiceExceptionFacade() {

    RestServiceExceptionFacade exceptionFacade = new RestServiceExceptionFacade();
    exceptionFacade.setExposeInternalErrorDetails(this.exposeInternalErrorDetails);
    return exceptionFacade;
  }

}
```

pom.xml

```
...
<dependency>
      <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
      <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
      <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
      <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.oasp.java.modules</groupId>
      <artifactId>oasp4j-batch</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zuul</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.oasp.java.modules</groupId>
      <artifactId>oasp4j-logging</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.oasp.java.modules</groupId>
      <artifactId>oasp4j-beanmapping</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.oasp.java.modules</groupId>
      <artifactId>oasp4j-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.oasp.java.modules</groupId>
      <artifactId>oasp4j-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.oasp.java.modules</groupId>
      <artifactId>oasp4j-basic</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.oasp.java.starters</groupId>
      <artifactId>oasp4j-starter-cxf-client-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.oasp.java.starters</groupId>
      <artifactId>oasp4j-starter-cxf-client-ws</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.oasp.java.starters</groupId>
      <artifactId>oasp4j-starter-cxf-server-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.oasp.java.starters</groupId>
      <artifactId>oasp4j-starter-cxf-server-ws</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.oasp.java.modules</groupId>
      <artifactId>oasp4j-jpa-envers</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.oasp.java.modules</groupId>
      <artifactId>oasp4j-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- for SpringDispatcher Servlet -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- for HttpInvoker -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSP -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <!--
      <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
      </dependency>
    -->

    <!-- for Object Relational Mapping (JPA/Hibernate) -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate EntityManager for JPA (implementation) -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Database -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
      <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
      <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- hibernate -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>cglib</groupId>
      <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- CXF for REST and Webservices -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
      <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>asm</groupId>
          <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
      <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
      <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
      <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-service-description</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
      <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Web Sockets -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Tests -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.oasp.java.modules</groupId>
      <artifactId>oasp4j-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
      <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
      <version>11.2.0.3</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
      <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
      <version>11.2.0.3</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
      <version>2.10.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-ws</artifactId>
    </dependency>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create a `Docket` bean, something like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket publicApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.foo.bar"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.ant("/api/**"))
                .build()
                .securitySchemes(Collections.singletonList(new BasicAuth("basic")))
                .apiInfo(apiInfo());
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfo(
                "REST Service API",
                "V1 Service API endpoints",
                "1",
                "Terms of Service",
                new Contact("Digital Support", "www.foo.bar", "digitalsupport@foo.bar"),
                "Apache 2.0",
                "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html",
                Collections.<VendorExtension>emptyList()
        );
    }
}
```

I have this in a stand-alone config class, rather than putting it in the main spring-boot application class.

The only thing in addition to this config is some annotations on the controller methods like this: `@ApiOperation(value = "Get Paged Accounts. Requires ADMIN Role",
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)`

Comment: I have already tried using docket but Springfox only finds the classes annotated with "@RestController "and not the cxf ones annotated with "@Path"

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [cxf swagger example project](https://github.com/kprasad99/cxf-swagger-example), in order to generate `swagger.json` from CXF Rest service having Swagger Annotations. You need to add `cxf-rt-rs-service-description-swagger` maven dependency and add `Swagger2Feature` to `JAXRSServerFactoryBean`(in your case you have to set as `factory.setFeatures(new Swagger2Feature())`)